# Maven tests failing in Azure DevOps. java.io.FileNotFoundException: TestSuiteList.xls (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, linux, azure, maven, devops

I'm trying to lunch release pipeline in Azure DevOps for Maven tests automation and I keep getting this error:

> 2020-03-13T16:12:59.0792106Z java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   TestSuiteList.xls (No such file or directory)

Location of the file is correct, but maybe there is a problem with path. I have tried:

```
public static final String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
public static String cloudbrokerBase = "http://localhost:9000/Cloudbroker";

public static WebDriver /*void*/ init() throws IOException{
    //To Initialize logger service.
    Add_Log = Logger.getLogger("rootLogger");

    if (System.getProperty("cloudbrokerBase", null) != null ){
        cloudbrokerBase = System.getProperty("cloudbrokerBase");
    }

    String basePath = "";
    if (Platform.getCurrent().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("MAC")) {
        basePath = currentDir + "//src//test//java//resources//";
    } else if (Platform.getCurrent().toString().contains("WIN")) {
        basePath = currentDir + "\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\";
    }
```

OR

```
public static final String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
public static String cloudbrokerBase = "http://localhost:9000/Cloudbroker";

public static WebDriver /*void*/ init() throws IOException{
    //To Initialize logger service.
    Add_Log = Logger.getLogger("rootLogger");

    if (System.getProperty("cloudbrokerBase", null) != null ){
        cloudbrokerBase = System.getProperty("cloudbrokerBase");
    }

    String basePath = "";
    if (Platform.getCurrent().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("MAC")) {
        basePath = currentDir + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "test" + File.separator + "java" + File.separator +"resources" + File.separator;
    } else if (Platform.getCurrent().toString().contains("WIN")) {
        basePath = currentDir + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "test" + File.separator + "java" + File.separator +"resources" + File.separator;
    }
```

Both works locally on my Windows 10, but when I use Linux Agent on DevOps I get the error. I need it to work on any machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
String basePath = "";
if (Platform.getCurrent().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("MAC")) {
    basePath = currentDir + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "test" + File.separator + "java" + File.separator +"resources" + File.separator;
} else if (Platform.getCurrent().toString().contains("WIN")) {
    basePath = currentDir + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "test" + File.separator + "java" + File.separator +"resources" + File.separator;
}
```

Here `basePath` will have value of empty String if `Platform.getCurrent().toString()` is not `WIN` nor `MAC`, and the empty base path means that the application will look for the file in the current directory.